# Help Me Identify My Uncle's Old Elevated Chainstay Bike

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

Please help me identify my uncle's old bike. I will greatly apppreciate all of you that willing to help mi.

Thanks to all in advance who help!

[image: Vintage Elevated Chainstay]

Comment: Not that old, with V-brakes.

Comment: The logo looks like it says Yoshimura. There’s a modern company with a very similar logo. https://yoshimuracycling.com/pages/faqs

Comment: @DanielRHicks Shimano introduced their V-brakes in '96. It might also have been a later upgrade. The frame has old-fashioned quill stems. Those dissappeard from quality mountain bikes also in the mid 90s. (Road bikes were later 96' (Pinarello) and 98' quill stems (Trek), '97 threadless (Pinarello).

Comment: Antonius, let us know a bit more about the bike, if you please? Let's sumarize what we see here: 6-speed Shimano indexed derailleur. Shift levers on the bars. That indicates  Rust on rear triangle has been oversprayed, bike has not been moved since (still paint on the cogs). Brake tracks worn, must have been actually ridden. Aluminium platform pedals that are certainly newer than rest. With that amount of rust, the bike is not worth fixing.

Comment: @WeiwenNg, correct, the logo is Yoshimura, but when i search on google, i haven't got any information about Yoshimura company making a bicycle. Or perhaps, i search it wrong?

Comment: @gschenk what kind of information do you want? Yes the bike is quite rusted everywhere, at first, i have no intention to fix it, but after i tried to ride it, surprisingly it feel quite good. The shifting still smooth even with that amount of rust and old cassette, the frame is pretty light too. And its me who spray some paint on rear triangle :P

still looking for someone who can identify the brand and the original look :D

Comment: @gschenk - To me, "old" is a bike with cottered cranks.

Comment: My money is on early 1990's with upgrades/repairs (brakes to V, rear derailleur is newer than 1990's). Shimano was 7 speed above Altus by 1990 (Altus still had a 6speed option).  By mid 1990's, geometry had slackened from what I see on this bike and shocks were becoming common.  Would be interested to know if any markings on hubs and levers/shifters (Shimano by 1990's was labeling tuff above Altus with the range)

Comment: @gscheck - to me also, that is also not 'old', its when I bought got into the newfangled thing called Moutain biking. :)

Comment: I'd guess the V brakes were replacements for cantilevers, similar to the picture in the answer.  The stem may have a hole down through it for the original brake cable.

Comment: I have to say that white rattlecan paint job in the rear triangle could be a lot better - whoever did it managed to get overspray on cassette, chain, and rear derailleur/cable.   Could be better.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but this looks awfully similar to an AlpineStars CroMega.

[image]
 1991 AlpineStars Cro-mega from [Retrobike](https://www.retrobike.co.uk/threads/1991-alpinestars-cro-mega-lx.392534/)

Comment: Do you have a picture tied to an AlpineStars CroMega?  If so, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: Similar but not it. Seatpost on Alpinestars is bend, and seatstay/seatpost intersection detail is very different.

Comment: Good spotting but this bike has a straight downtube between headtube and BB, whereas OP's is a straight line from headtube to rear dropouts.   They are of similar overall aesthetic, so the time period of 1991 probably lines up within a year or two.  That certainly helps.